# How do you compile LINQ queries against CRM 2011?

Tags: linq, compilation, crm

How do you compile LINQ queries against CRM 2011?

I'm connecting to CRM 2011 using the Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll and use a Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmOrganizationServiceContext _SvcContext which is generated from a connectionstring in the app.config file. I have the following LINQ query which works great:

```
var vdiConfigDataSet = 
   (from SvrToPubProfSet in _SvcContext.vdi_publicationprofile_vdi_serverSet
    join PubProfSet in _SvcContext.vdi_publicationprofileSet
    on SvrToPubProfSet.vdi_publicationprofileid equals PubProfSet.Id
    join SvrSet in _SvcContext.vdi_serverSet
    on SvrToPubProfSet.vdi_serverid equals SvrSet.Id
    where SvrSet.vdi_address == System.Environment.MachineName // This will ignore case

    select new
      {
        // Data from Server record
        RootPath = SvrSet.vdi_rootpath, // This is the same for all Publication Profiles
        SvrAddr = SvrSet.vdi_address,

        // Data from N:N relationship record(s) vdi_publicationprofile_vdi_serverSet
        SvrId = SvrToPubProfSet.vdi_serverid,
        PubProfId = SvrToPubProfSet.vdi_publicationprofileid,

        // Data from Publication Profile record(s)
        PubProfName = PubProfSet.vdi_name,
        RelativePath = PubProfSet.vdi_relativepath,
        ReportRelativePath = PubProfSet.vdi_reportrelativepath,
        ReportFilenameSeed = PubProfSet.vdi_reportfilenameseed,
        SubSystemType = PubProfSet.vdi_subsystemtype,
        ModifiedOn = PubProfSet.ModifiedOn
      }).ToList();
```

This is quite a large query which gets executed repeatedly. I want to compile it down. I have tried the following:

```
public static readonly Func<DataContext, Object> s_compiledQuery =
  CompiledQuery.Compile<DataContext, Object>
  (ctx  =>
  (from SvrToPubProfSet in ctx.GetTable<vdi_publicationprofile_vdi_server>()
   join PubProfSet in ctx.GetTable<vdi_publicationprofile>()
   on SvrToPubProfSet.vdi_publicationprofileid equals PubProfSet.Id
   join SvrSet in ctx.GetTable<vdi_server>()
   on SvrToPubProfSet.vdi_serverid equals SvrSet.Id
   where SvrSet.vdi_address == System.Environment.MachineName // This will ignore case

   select new
   {
     // Data from Server record
     RootPath = SvrSet.vdi_rootpath, // This is the same for all Publication Profiles
     SvrAddr = SvrSet.vdi_address,

     // Data from N:N relationship record(s) vdi_publicationprofile_vdi_serverSet
     SvrId = SvrToPubProfSet.vdi_serverid,
     PubProfId = SvrToPubProfSet.vdi_publicationprofileid,

     // Data from Publication Profile record(s)
     PubProfName = PubProfSet.vdi_name,
     RelativePath = PubProfSet.vdi_relativepath,
     ReportRelativePath = PubProfSet.vdi_reportrelativepath,
     ReportFilenameSeed = PubProfSet.vdi_reportfilenameseed,
     SubSystemType = PubProfSet.vdi_subsystemtype,
     ModifiedOn = PubProfSet.ModifiedOn
   }).ToList());
...

var vdiConfigDataSet2 = s_compiledQuery(_SvcContext); //ERROR _SvcContext is not DataContext type
```

but I need a `DataContext` type object and I don't know how to get that from the `Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmOrganizationServiceContext` type object.

Anyone have any ideas how to get the `DataContext` or perhaps a more elegant solution on compiling LINQ queries for CRM 2011?

Answer (score 0):

The CRM service context proxy is not based on Entity Framework's Data Context, instead "under the covers" is ODATA / SOAP. You cannot compile a CRM query because the `CompileQuery` Class generic arg must inherit from `ObjectContext`.

One thing you may want to look into is using this parameter:
    /codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization, Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration"
With the SDK's code generation tool (crmsvcutil.exe) as this will enable traversing "navigation properties" in a CRM linq query, thereby alleviating your joins.